# NativeScript - Emulated Device is unreachable / Device is not authorized

Tags: android, nativescript

I am trying to get NativeScript working on my machine using a virtual android device. I am on a linux (ubuntu 16) machine.

I followed this [installation guide](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/ns-setup-linux)

I was able to start a virtual device using Android Studio's AVD Manager. On the launched virtual device I activated the developer options and enabled USB debugging.

Running `tns doctor` produces:

```
$ tns doctor
NOTE: You can develop for iOS only on Mac OS X systems.
To be able to work with iOS devices and projects, you need Mac OS X Mavericks or later.

Your components are up-to-date: 
nativescript,tns-core-modules,tns-android,tns-ios

No issues were detected.
```

After that I created the HelloWorldAPP using `tns create HelloWorld --template nativescript-template-ng-tutorial` which worked just fine. But when trying to launch the APP I get:

```
$ tns run android 
Searching for devices...
Skipping prepare.
Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: The device is not authorized. Please use the --emulator flag to run the application on on an emulator.
```

I read I could check the status of my devices like this:

```
$ tns devices

Connected devices & emulators
Searching for devices...
iTunes is not available for this operating system. You will not be able to work with connected iOS devices.
┌───┬─────────────┬──────────┬───────────────────┬────────┬─────────────┐
│ # │ Device Name │ Platform │ Device Identifier │ Type   │ Status      │
│ 1 │             │ Android  │ emulator-5554     │ Device │ Unreachable │
```

All I read on my search for a solution so far was real device related (like using USB 2.0 instead of 3.0) or using different operating systems and therefore the "fixes" I found weren't applicable.

Thank you for your time!

Raphael Hippe

Comment: Try to restarting the device, it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is a problem with the virtual device "Nexus". I managed to make the HelloWorldApp work using the Pixel2 with API v27 patch.

Cheers,

Raphael Hippe

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps:

1. Ensure that you have full Admin right over the machine.
2. Try launching the Command prompt as Administrator as it will be required for the node and nativescript to function properly.
3. Try using Google API's for the API level section while creating the emulator.
4. Try launching Android SDK manager in Admin mode and try to launch the emulator.

Hope this would resolve your issues.